# killing fragment or activity kill background threads?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-fragments

I started doing some disk I/O in an asynctask within a fragment.

Does opening a new activity/fragment (on top of the previous fragment) kill the background thread? I think not for this action, but if I kill the fragment a different way or finish() an activity does it kill the background thread?

I am contemplating putting the I/O in a service with broadcast receivers but it may not be necessary depending on the answers here.

Comment: Please read the AsyncTask documentation -- it's intended specifically for "short" tasks. If you have a task which would frequently outlast your foreground activity, by all means, place it in a Service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the official documentation :

> AsyncTasks should ideally be used for short operations (a few seconds at the most.) If you need to keep threads running for long periods of time, it is highly recommended you use the various APIs provided by the java.util.concurrent pacakge such as Executor, ThreadPoolExecutor and FutureTask.

I am pretty sure the background thread isn't destroyed but is useless at that point. Say an activity started a Async task and updates the text of a button in postExecute. The problem is if the user does something unexpected like rotating his phone the activity is recreated and the context for the Async task is invalid. So it won't update the button text.

Have a look at the link below for better understanding and workarounds:

http://blogactivity.wordpress.com/2011/09/01/proper-use-of-asynctask/